# Расположение сервисов в доменных службах и службах приложения в луковой архитектуре

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, asp.net-core, архитектура, ddd

У меня есть бот, вот его основной функционал:
Пользователь оплачивает подписку, с помощью нее добавляет Инстаграм и авторизует его. Далее он создает работу (сущность Work), заполняет ее необходимыми данными (сообщение, откуда брать получателей) и запускает работу. Эта работа в фоне получит пользователей в соответствии с типом работы и отправит им сообщения.

Я хочу реализовать луковую архитектуру и не совсем понимаю, куда располагать следующие службы. Мое предположение:

Интерфейс платежной системы должен быть в доменных службах, а реализация должна быть в инфраструктуре. Так же и с инстаграмом - его основная задача это авторизация и отправка сообщений. Оба эти интерфейса должны быть на уровне доменных служб, но с реализацией в инфраструктуре. Интерфейс запуска задач тоже должен находиться в доменных службах с реализацией в инфраструктуре, так как основная задача сущности Work это выполнять в фоне какие-либо действия. А вот сама служба обработки сущности Work должна иметь не только интерфейс, но и реализацию на уровне доменных служб.

Варианты использования к примеру будут: создавать работу, добавлять в нее инстаграмы и запускать.

Вот примеры интерфейсов:

```cs
public interface IWorkScheduler
{
    Task StartWorkNowAsync(Work work);
    Task ScheduleWorkAsync(Work work, DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset);
    Task CancelWorkAsync(Work work);
}
```

```cs
public interface IBackgroundJobService //Служба, в которой и происходит выполнение всех фоновых задач, реализована в доменных службах
{
    Task ProcessingMailingAsync(Work workDto, CancellationToken token);
    Task<List<Work>> ProcessingDivideWorkAsync(Work workDto, CancellationToken token);
    Task SaveAfterContinuedAsync(Work workDto);
}
```

```cs
public interface IInstagramUsersGetterService
{
     Task<List<long>> GetUsersAsync(Work workDto, CancellationToken token);
}
```

```cs
public interface IPaymentSystem
{
    Task<Payment> CreatePaymentAsync(User user, int countSubscribes);
    Task<Payment> GetPaymentInfoAsync(string id);
}
```

```cs
public interface ITelegramService
{
    public Task SendMessageAsync(long id, string message)
}
```

```cs
public class Work //Сущность Work, в нее будут добавлены некоторые бизнес правила
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<InstagramLite> Instagrams { get; set; } = new();
    public List<long> InstagramPks { get; set; } = new();
    public string? Message { get; set; }
    public string? JobId { get; set; }
    public string? Hashtag { get; set; }
    public WorkUsersType UsersType { get; set; }
    public WorkType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public int CountErrors { get; set; }
    public int CountSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Instagram //Сущность Instagram
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Password { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? StateData { get; set; }
    public string? TwoFactorLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public string? ChallengeLoginInfo { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public UserLite? User { get; set; }
    public Proxy? Proxy { get; set; }

    public void SetProxy(Proxy proxy) => Proxy = proxy;
}
```

Comment: Какой у вас вариант ASP.NET Core ?  MVC, Razor Pages, Blazor или вы еще не определились?

Comment: MVC. А разве это имеет значение?

Comment: Значение имеет,  если хотите получить адекватный ответ, то давайте максимум информации о задаче. Не совсем понимаю,  идею организации вашего приложения в многослойной(или луковой) архитектуре. Мне кажется что Вы путаете понятия Интерфейса, как специального объекта в языке C# и интерфейса в более широком смысле этого слова, как некоего соглашения о формате передваемых данных между разными частями в монолитном приложении или как отдельных сервисов (API) в микросервисной архитектуре.

Comment: Вот  в этом [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Rocky-Part-2), пример редизайна интернет магазина на ASP.NET Core MVC с многослойной архитектурой для .NET 5.

Comment: А в этмо [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Mango), аналогичное решение для интернет-магазина,  но с расширение этой же идеи многослойной архитектуры, но уже с выделением таких слоев в отдельные микросервисы с WEB-API, при этом основное веб-приложение также написано на ASP.NET Core MVC, решение сделано для .NET 6.